# <identifier>がありません

Tags: android, java

趣味で学び始めた、全くの初心者です。あまりにレベルの低い質問であればすみません。
ほかの人の質問を見てみましたが、よくわかりませんでした。

MainActivityをつくり、そこにSpinnerを置いて、Dropdownリストからメニュを選択すると、ほかのActivityに遷移するようにしたいという、単純な部分でつまずいています。
Runすると、 以下の

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
MainActivity(toolbar);
```

の部分に関し、`<Identifier>`がありません、というエラーがでます。
これは何を意味するでしょうか。
教えて頂ければ幸いです。
以下、全文です。
必要な情報あれば、補足致します。

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String[] items = new String [] {"1","2","3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        dropdown.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position==0){
              Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Course1Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);}
                }

            });
        }


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        MainActivity(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        })
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `MainActivity(toolbar);`とはどういう意味でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
そこが変なのですよね。
見直します。
どうもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toolbar を ActionBar としてセットアップしたいのであれば、

```
MainActivity(toolbar);
```

ではなく、

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

のはずです。

> `<Identifier>`がありません、というエラーがでます。これは何を意味するでしょうか。

Java のコンパイルエラーですね。`MainActivity(toolbar)`とした場合、Toolbarオブジェクトを引数に取る、`MainActivity` という名前のメソッド（関数）があり、それを実行するという意味になりますが、そのような識別子（Identifier）のメソッドは存在しない（定義されていない）と言われています。

一方、`setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`というメソッドは、AppCompatActivity のメソッドとして定義されているものです（[公式リファレンス](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar))）。

またちなみに、クラス名である MainActivity と同名の MainActivity(何らかの引数または、引数なし)という形式のメソッドは、コンストラクターと呼ばれる特殊なメソッドになります。GUI に関する API は Android 特有のものを使うことになるので、そこまで Java をやりこむ必要はありませんが、初級の Java の勉強は一通りは別途（平行して）行っておいた方が良いと思います。

Comment: Hata様
丁寧なご回答、誠にありがとうございます。
直してやってみます。
ご親切な回答に対し、メダル？バッジ？のようなものを差し上げるシステムがあると思うのですが、やり方がいまいちわからず、すみません。

Tora

Comment: @torachan [回答を承認するには](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)に説明がありますが、（今回存在するのは私の回答のみとなりますが）得られた回答のうち、質問者にとって一番役に立ったという回答を選んでその左横のチェックマークをクリックして緑色にすることで、対応できます。また複数回答がある場合でも、役に立つ（反対の立たない）という投票（上向き三角・下向き三角）は、すべての回答に対して行なえます。